External HDDs become read only every 2 days
I decided to have a media server running Linux Mint and CasaOS (Plex) and 2 HDDs connected via USB.
All works fine after I turn it on however, after 2 days or so, the drives become read only, causing Plex and CasaOS to stop working.
Moreover, if I try to restart it or shut it down it hangs so I need to force shut down.
And it took me a while to notice why things stopped working every 2 days or so.
After that, when I turn it on, if the HDDs are connected, it hangs again.
I need to turn of the enclosure, turn on the PC, then turn on the HDDs and restart.
After that, it works again for a few days and same thing happens.
I'm kinda lost and I would appreciate any suggestions, especially since I am not mainly a Linux user.
I would've posted this on CasaOS forum but to me it seems more of an OS issue.

Uee df to see what the device names (/dev/sdXX), then sudo journalctl /dev/sdXX will show interesting logs.

@waltinator As far as I can tell, there's no issue https://pastebin.com/U2avBU0i

My only idea would be to try rotate out the components of your system to another working system to see if you can narrow this down to one  unit. .... If you get help on the CasaOS forum, please post an answer. You can self-accept your answer after 48 hrs and gain valuable reputation points.

@shellter Thanks. I know the external enclosure has a autosuspend function, after 30 minutes. This was my first thought. So I created a cronjob that keeps them awake. Then, I  made sure the OS does not cut the power when there is no activity (found this tip on Mint forum). I will post this on CasaOS forum and their subreddit, see what I can find.

@shellter Issue occurred again and posted an update in the pastebin file
